# Select options missing after HTML form submit

Tags: forms, knockout.js

I have a form where I use KnockoutJS to dynamically populate several chained SELECT OPTIONS, but when I *submit* the form the selected values are not included in the GET request to the server.  Here is a sample HTML that has a regular HTML and a Knockout SELECT options:

```html
<form name=mainForm action="" method="GET" data-bind="submit: onSubmit">
    <input type=hidden name=hiddenId />
    <select name=htmlSelectName>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
    </select>
    <select name=koSelectName id=koSelectId 
                    data-bind="options: myOptions,
                               optionsCaption: 'Select...',
                               optionsText: 'optionText',
                               value: 'optionId'">                 
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="koViewModel/hidden.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

With the GET request, you can see the parameters from the htmlSelect are set back to the server, but the koSelect section is not sent back by default.  I wrote an onSubmit binding which copies the koSelect values to a hidden field, which does get sent back to the server:

```
var selectOptions = [
    {
        optionId : "A100",
        optionText: "Option A",
    },
    {
        optionId : "B200",
        optionText: "Option B",
    }
];

var viewModel = function(someOptions) {
    var self = this;
    self.myOptions = someOptions;
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable();
    console.log("Sending Option: " + self.selectedOption);

    self.onSubmit = function() {
        var k = document.getElementById("koSelectId");

        document.mainForm.hiddenId.value =  selectOptions[k.selectedIndex-1].optionId;

        alert("Got Knockout Option ("+k.selectedIndex+"): " + k.options[k.selectedIndex].text);
        console.log("Got Knockout Option ("+k.selectedIndex+"): " + k.options[k.selectedIndex].text);
        console.log("Got Knockout Value ("+k.selectedIndex+"): " + document.mainForm.hiddenId.value);
        confirm("Click OK after reviewing the console output.  Then examine the GET params.");
        return true;
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(selectOptions));
```

The result with the GET query string is:

```
myapp?hiddenId=A100&htmlSelectName=Three&koSelectName=
```

But is there an easier way to get the KO select options returned on submit without copying to a hidden field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up two things in the way a `select` should be handled with KO:

- `value` (or `selectedOptions` for multi-select) is the observable holding the value the user selected, and is needed to make sure something is marked as selected - *you're using `optionId` but probably meant to use a not-yet-existing observable*.
- `optionsValue` is for marking the property on your view model to be used as the `value` attribute on `option`s - *you're missing this property but probably meant to use `optionId`*.

Here's an example that works as expected:

```html
<form name="mainForm" action="" method="GET" data-bind="submit: onSubmit">
  <select name="koSelectName"
          data-bind="options: myOptions,
                     optionsCaption: 'Select...',
                     optionsText: 'optionText',
                     optionsValue: 'optionId',
                     value: 'selectedOption'">                 
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```javascript
var selectOptions = [
  {
    optionId : "A100",
    optionText: "Option A",
  },
  {
    optionId : "B200",
    optionText: "Option B",
  }
];

var viewModel = function(someOptions) {
  var self = this;
  self.myOptions = someOptions;
  self.selectedOption = ko.observable();
  self.onSubmit = function() {
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
    return true;
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(selectOptions));
```